# How do you check whether two strings are equal?

Tags: c++, string, comparison, character

If I have two pieces of character data, what is the best way to compare them (test for equality with `==`)?

That is, which type is best for this comparison; a `const char*`, a `std::string`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your goal is simply to compare strings for equality then it doesn't really matter whether you use null-terminated strings or some string container like `std::string`.

You can use `std::strcmp` to compare two null-terminated strings just as easily as you can use `operator==` to compare two `std::string` objects.  The overloaded operator does make code cleaner and easier to read in most cases.

Of course, since you're programming in C++, you should be using `std::string` or some other string container and not manipulating raw null-terminated data, wherever possible.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence, especially for "wherever possible".